Why $\chi(\mathscr{F}_n)=n$ in Goss´ Basic structures of Function Fields?
I´m reading Basic Basic structures of Function Fields, and I'm trying to understand Proposition 6.2.3, which talks about a propiety of a torsion-free coherent $\mathscr{O}_X$-module $\mathscr{F}$ on a X complete curve. The book defines $\mathscr{F}_{j+t}=\mathscr{F}_j(P)$, where $P$ is a divisor of a curve. Then it says that, from general properties  of coherent cohomology, one sees that $\chi(\mathscr{F}_n)=n$.
Why is it? I think it's related to Riemman-Roch Theorem, but I'm not sure. Anyone can explain this or give some bibliography in order to understand this?
Thanks in advance.

I think you're leaving out important context about the definition of the sheaves involved here, but it should be a consequence of tensoring the standard exact sequence $0\to\mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal{O}_X(P)\to \kappa(P)\to 0$ by $\mathcal{F}$. If you're interested in a more detailed answer, please add more information about the setup to your post.
